# How many classes does the equivalence relation partition the set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Looking for help on B) How many classes does the equivalence relation partition set X

> Consider the relations $R$ and $S$, defined on the set $X = \{1, 2, . . . , 99\}$ as follows.
>
> $xRy \iff x + y$ is a multiple of $11$,
>
> $xSy \iff x − y$ is a multiple of $11$.
>
> A) One of $R$ and $S$ is an equivalence relation, the other is not. Determine which is which and justify your answers.
>
> B) Into how many classes does the equivalence relation partition set $X$?

So far I've determined that S is the equivalence relation as R isn't reflexive or transitive. My only attempt at B is that there is 11-1=10 non-zero congruence classes, so does each one correspond to a non-zero equivalence class?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where does this "non-zero" stuff come from?

Comment: I'm confused, does "non-zero" class mean it is not a multiple of 11?

Comment: A non-zero equivalence class means an equivalence class that does not contain zero. The fundamental theorem of equivalence relations induces a partition on the set so the zero equivalence class is unambiguously defined.

Comment: So would 10 be the correct answer?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Sorry, but "a zero equivalence class" is a bit of a nonsense on a set that doesn't even contain zero, such that the given set $X$.

Comment: @zipirovich I guess you're using a different definition of zero. Give the set a group structure by defining modulo arithmetic in the usual way with some caveat about reducing to the lowest representatives before multiplying to ensure closure and it has an identity element and that's what I'm calling the zero equivalence class. I assume you mean the set doesn't contain the identity element of the integers but I guess it just seemed obvious to me what he meant given the context.

Comment: What's wrong with a "zero equivalence class?  Doe $11 -11=0$ make $11$ any *less* equivalent?  Where did you get this weird idea that you aren't supposed to count the the equivalence class to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count them.

$1 R 12 R 23 R 34 R .... R 90$

$2 R 13 R 24 R 35 R .... R 91$

....

$10 R 21 R 32 R 43 R..... R 98$

$11 R 22 R 33 R 44 R ..... R 99$

That's 11.

It doesn't make any sense to subtract the "zero" equivalence class for 2 reasons.

1) The "zero" equivalence class is *STILL* an equivalence class so why they heck would you omit it?  *NOWHERE* in the question does it say *ANYTHING* about how many non-zero equivalence classes; it ask how many equivalence classes.  And $\{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99\}$ is *certainly* an equivalence class, isn't it?

2) Since no method of "addition" has been defined or discussed, there is no meaning to defining any one of the equivalence classes as be a "zero" equivalence class.  *IF* we were to define $\{x|x R c\} + \{x|x R d\} = \{x| x R (d+c\pm 11k \text{ for some integer } k)\}$ and define $[0]$ as the equivelence clas so that $[0] + \{x|x R c\} = \{x|x R c\}$ then, yes, $\{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99\} = [0]$.  But again, so what, it's *still* an equivalence class, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To show $S$ is an equivalence relation you can either verify directly that it is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric or demonstrate that the relation partitions the set and use the fundamental theorem of equivalence relations. If you can demonstrate the existence of the congruence classes you have such a partition and that's sufficient to demonstrate that you have an equivalence relation. As you've deduced there are eleven such classes, and ten of them do not contain zero. I would also encourage you to consider the first method of directly verifying the three defining properties as it's both instructive and relatively easy.

Comment: So is the answer 10 for B) correct?

Comment: @RealGib: No, it's not.

Comment: @RealGib 10 is the number of non-zero equivalence classes modulo $11$ but that is not all of them. Can you figure out what you've missed?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I dont think I can, am I missing the zero equivalence classes?

Comment: "None of the equivalence classes on X contain 0"  Even if $0$ was in the initial set, why shouldn't you count it?  Where did the OP get the idea that you aren't supposed to include zero?

Comment: @RealGib Yes - that's exactly it! You forgot the zero class for a total of eleven.

Comment: Except as Morgan Rodgers points out none of them actually contain zero.  And he didn't "forget" them.  He deliberately left them out for confused reasons that do not apply.

Comment: @fleablood yeah but as I pointed out in the comments to the main question it does contain zero assuming you mean an identity on an Abelian group. Morgan Rodgers continued insistence on ignoring this obvious interpretation of the OPs comments doesn't seem relevant and can ignored as a superfluous detail since the OP and I agree on the nomenclature in the discussion. Indeed, I find the idea of using non-standard terminology just to deal with the irrelevant detail of which members of the integers are including in the set S when only the properties of the integers modulo 11 matter.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You are reading more into the question than is being asked. This is not a question about arithmetic modulo 11 (though that is the hidden underlying concept). This is a question about an equivalence relation on a set $X$. We do **not** have $X = \mathbb{Z}$, we do **not** have $0 \in X$, and there is **no group operation being defined or discussed**. You and the OP "agree[ing] on nomenclature" is leading to confusion and ending up with a wrong answer, where they are leaving out one of the equivalence classes for mysterious reasons.

Comment: "Morgan Rodgers continued insistence on ignoring this obvious interpretation of the OPs comments".  But it goes both ways.  I agree that "$\{11,...99\}$ do not contain $0$ as so can't be 'zero' modulo class" is a bit too oblique and inaccurate and $11\equiv 0 \mod 11$ does *indeed* mean $\{11,...99\}$ *is* the zero element.  But on another, and very important level  A "zero" (additive identity) element can only be defined if addition on the classes (and NOT on the elements of the classes) is defined.  So it is not unjustified.

Comment: ... so I mostly agree with Morgan Rodgers although I believe saying "it isn't a zero module as it doesn't contain zero" evades the issue that it actually isn't a zero module because the means for which it is "zero" are not stated.  Of more concern is... why leave out the zero modules.  These seem to much of a "monkey see; monkey do" approach to math that is doomed to failure.  You don't just do everything one way despite whether that is what a question asks.  If was asked how many elments does $\{0,1,6,8\}$ you don't answer 3 because zero doesn't count and you don't answer "it goes to 8".

Comment: @MorganRodgers I'm simply more concerned about accurate communication than hairsplitting. What you call a "hidden underlying concept" I consider completely obvious and given that RealGib apparently found it obvious too I didn't see any particular reason to try and stuff the genji back in the bottle.